# how to disable horizontal drag in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am working on a bootstrap modal and I've use a sortable+draggable plug-in, the result looks fine, but when I drag the div horizontally there appears a white area and a horizontal scroll bar, I've already removed the scroll bar by using `overflow-x: hidden;` in css. How do I disable the horizontal drag now?

there's the [screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaCBK.jpg)

the javascript, css, html code are as follows:

```js
$(document.body).on('click','#sssort',function(){
            $('#sortable').sortable(); 
            $('#sortable').disableSelection(); 
        });
```

```css
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
    #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; background-color: #DDD；}
    #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
    .modal_footer{padding:15px;}
    .modal-body{
        height: 800px;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mymodal_sort" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mymodal_sort" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <div class="listItem" id="item1" style="background: #E0EEFD;height:60px;line-height: 60px;overflow: hidden; ">        
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <p>时间1111111110</p>            
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            title
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            图片
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            链接
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            位置
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                            发布者
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_footer">
            <button id="save_sort" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sortable">提交</button>
            <button id="close" type="button" class="btn btn-default">取消</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please? And relevant parts of the HTML/CSS?

Comment: Any links to the online version?

Comment: I've add a link of the screenshot ,sorry for couldn't make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sortable `axis` option in order to constrain the draggable movement on an axis.

> If defined, the items can be dragged only horizontally or vertically.
>   Possible values: "x", "y".

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis

Code:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({ axis: "y"});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/174ypddq/